# It is showing Error in Keras, Classifier.Fit_Generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
# Convolutional Neural Network
# Installing Theano
# pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
# Installing Tensorflow
# pip install tensorflow
# Installing Keras
# pip install --upgrade keras
# Part 1 - Building the CNN
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages

    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Conv2D
    from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN

    classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution

    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling

    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer

    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening

    classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection

    classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compiling the CNN

    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,shear_range = 0.2,zoom_range = 0.2,horizontal_flip = True)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('E:\Major Project\Data\Wheat',target_size = (64, 64),batch_size = 32,class_mode = 'categorical')
    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('E:\Major Project\Data\Wheat1',target_size = (64, 64),batch_size = 32,class_mode = 'categorical')
    classifier.fit_generator(training_set,steps_per_epoch = 100,epochs = 5,validation_data = test_set,validation_steps = 200)
```

when I'm trying run this code, getting an error in line classifier.fit_generator
 "ZeroDivisionError".  which is something like "Integer Division or Modulo by Zero"

It is giving error in first Epoch only

Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Epoch 1/5

Even after giving the correct path for the image

Comment: can you show the folder structure.?

Comment: Please include the full error backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `flow_from_directory`. You must have the following folder structure.

```
./Dataset/
    ./Train/
        ../Folder_1/
            ../img_1.jpg
            ../img_2.jpg
            ............
        ../Folder_2/
            ../img_1.jpg
            ../img_2.jpg
```

Where Folder_i contains images of class i.

In your path `E:\Major Project\Data` you must have `n` folders each corresponding to each class.

Then you can call `flow_from_directory` as

`train_datagen.flow_from_directory('E:\Major Project\Data\',target_size = (64, 64),batch_size = 32,class_mode = 'categorical')`

You will get an output like this

```
Found xxxx images belonging to yyyy classes
```

and if everything else is correct the model will start training

After training if you want to use `flow_from_directory` to make predictions with the help of `predict_generator` you can do like this.

You can change the value of batch_size in flow_from_directory from default value (which is batch_size=32 ) to batch_size=1. Then set the steps of predict_generator to the total number of your test images.

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(200, 200),
        color_mode="rgb",
        shuffle = False,
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=1)

filenames = test_generator.filenames
nb_samples = len(filenames)

predict = model.predict_generator(test_generator,steps = nb_samples)
```

If you want to predict on a single image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('path_to_file')
img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))

img = img.reshape(1, 64, 64, 3)

model.predict(img)
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the Prediction part works, As for prediction I have used import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('E:/Major Project/Data/Wheaty.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices

# {'Tomato': 0, 'Rice': 1, 'Wheat': 2}
if int(result[0][0]) == 1:
    prediction = 'Tomato'
elif int(result[0][1]) == 1:
    prediction = 'Rice'
else:
    prediction = 'Wheat'
print (prediction)

Comment: @HimanshuBaghmar you want to use `flow_from_directory` for prediction.?

Comment: no, for prediction I don't want to use flow_from_directory , I want to test for the single image

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved the issue